# Web3-Py : Nonce Transaction Overwriting Problem

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, web3py

hello I am using python web3 to send transactions but nonce is the problem my code is

```
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("https://rpc.tomochain.com/"))
mainWallet = '0xAad6a88877E6AB7FbC33fdAce672780A85Fc88a8'
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(mainWallet)
amount_to_send = 0.01
private_key = 'xxxxxxxx'

tx = {
        'nonce': nonce,
        'to': to_address,
        'value': w3.toWei(amount_to_send, 'ether'),
        'gas': 21000,
        'gasPrice': w3.toWei('0.3', 'gwei')
    }

sign_tx = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, private_key)
tran_hash = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(sign_tx.rawTransaction)
txn = w3.toHex(tran_hash)
print(txn)
```

**The Above code handle transactions well** but the problem is when more than 1 user tries to withdraw nonce problem come suppose
user 1 request withdraw of 0.001 & user 2 request withdraw of 0.002 and both of them request at the same time then the 0.001 transactions got canceled and only 0.002 passed

**What can I do so the both of them pass**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a local [ACID-compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) of transactions and used nonces before broadcasting them out. [An example here](https://github.com/miohtama/sto/blob/master/sto/models/broadcastaccount.py#L10).

Comment: Its not to much detailed bro

Comment: I am here to answer the question, not writing your programs for you. The scope of an answer to write a full transaction nonce management system is massive. Study and get good.

Comment: @Mikko Ohtamaa Great answer :D thx btw. Wanted some inspiration.